# Optional data format in WCF uri, but NOT in query string params

Tags: wcf

Problem: I have the following requirement while developing in WCF 4:
Data format to return should be requested in uri template at the end BEFORE any possible query string. Example: /resource1/resoursce2.xml
This url should result in data returned in xml format. If ".xml" is omitted from the url (/resource1/resoursce2) then data should be returned in Json format. Futhermore, I need to do it with one operation contract (one uri template).
Question: does WCF 4 have any support for this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You need to do it using WCF Rest framework.
You can set up following pathes

1. /resource1/resource2/format/xml url that will return xml
2. /resource1/resource2/format/json url that will return json

My advice is to use route table for this

See this link how to implement it 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: Right, unfortunatelly the requirement is to do it with a single template, rather than 2.